# String to Json escape forward slash in nested json

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to convert a string into JSON. JsonObject of java gson. 
The string is a nested JSON structure in which forward-slash () is added as you can see in name its has \\". ( One \ to escape \ and one \ for ".

How to ignore inner \ and convert into JSON object. I was trying with replaceAll to escapse \\" but did not work as it replaces \" also

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String json = "[{\"key\":\"px\",\"mKeyValues\":[{\"hmKey\":\"qx\",\"value\":\"[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Test Equipment value\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"2\\\"}]\"}]}]";
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        json = json.replaceAll("\\\\","");
        System.out.println(json);
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

Actual Json is

```
[
  {
    "key": "px",
    "mKeyValues": [
      {
        "hmKey": "qx",
        "value": [
          {
            "name": "Test Equipment value",
            "status": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what you're expecting?

Comment: updated in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
json = json.replace("\"[","[").replace("]\"", "]").replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Solution with out replace

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            String json = "[{\"key\":\"px\",\"mKeyValues\":[{\"hmKey\":\"qx\",\"value\":\"[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Test Equipment value\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"2\\\"}]\"}]}]";
            System.out.println(json);
            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
            JsonObject mKeyValues0 = jsonObject.get(0).getAsJsonObject()
                    .get("mKeyValues").getAsJsonArray()
                    .get(0).getAsJsonObject();


            mKeyValues0.add("value", jsonParser.parse(mKeyValues0.get("value").getAsString() ));

            System.out.println(jsonObject);
        }
```

Comment: Can we do without replacing, because of JSON string might contain actual text like that which I do not want to replace

Comment: @Sumeet, if you do not want replacing, then will this output work for you?
[{"key":"px","mKeyValues":[{"hmKey":"qx","value":"[{\"name\":\"Test Equipment value\",\"status\":\"2\"}]"}]}]

Answer (score 1):

You should not parse it as jsonObject since it is a jsonArray get this as jsonArray, something like this

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String json = "[{\"key\":\"px\",\"mKeyValues\":[{\"hmKey\":\"qx\",\"value\":\"[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Test Equipment value\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"2\\\"}]\"}]}]";
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        json = json.replace("\"[","[").replace("]\"", "]").replace("\\\"", "\"");
        System.out.println(json);
        JsonArray jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
}
```